# How to start and stop both the webcam stream and microphone in React JSX using WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, jsx

I already have getUserMedia working in my ReactJSX file. I'm new to ReactJSX, and i've viewed some stackoverflow posts related to this, but unfortunately many of the existing instructions include a line of code/function that is deprecated by webRTC.

However, I haven't been able to figure how to stop the web cam stream and microphone in **React JSX**, in particular. And since this language is quite new for me, can anyone help me?

This is the working code I have before the `return()` tag in React JSX

```
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true
    })
    .then(stream => {
      document.getElementById("startstream").srcObject = stream;
    })
```

And this is the working code I have to display and enable the camera and microphone after the `return()` tag in React JSX:

```
<video id="startstream" autoPlay />
```

Both of those code snippets work, and it allows the user to start the stream/start their microphone, but how do I *start* and *stop* the webcam/microphone using a button in ReactJSX? I've seen something similar online using another coding language, but if anyone code help me to get it to work with ReactJSX, that would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you use onclick event, then clear the srcObject?

Comment: @FahmiJabbar i'm new to React JSX, so how would I do that? The solution below doesn't work to stop the camera in JSX, and i think clearing the srcObject is possible solution

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class WebRTCSample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { localStream: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  startWebCam = () => {
    const that = this;
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        that.setState({ localStream: stream });
      });
  };

  stopWebCam = () => {
    this.state.localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      track.stop();
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/* <h1>Hello GetUserMedia</h1> */}
        {this.state.localStream && (
          <video
            autoPlay
            ref={(video) => {
              if (video) {
                video.srcObject = this.state.localStream;
              }
            }}
            // src={this.state.localStream}
          />
        )}
        <div className="startStopWebCam">
          <button
            className="WebCamButton"
            onClick={this.startWebCam.bind(this)}
          >
            Start
          </button>
          <button className="WebCamButton" onClick={this.stopWebCam.bind(this)}>
            Stop
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WebRTCSample;
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/getusermedia-react-forked-sgc46?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: How do I show a button that stops the stream to the user in the front-end using React JSX though?

Comment: @anonymousowl Are you asking how to render a `button`? Just use `<button onClick={stopWebCam}>Stop Webcam</button/>` tags and it will be rendered.

Comment: Oh ok, I tried this, and for some reason the button doesn't make the stopWebCam work on JSX. Also, I am using JSX, so class WebRTCSample extends React.Component { } doesn't work in the JSX syntax

Comment: So you were actually right about the `<button onClick={stopWebCam}>Stop Webcam</button/>` part in ReactJSX. But in JSX, I am not allowed to do the first 8 lines of the code you have written in app.js. I can do `const className = () => { };` but not all the code related to the first 8 lines. So I believe that is why it's not working

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi Basically how can I do it without 'class WebRTCSample extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {super(props); this.localStream = null ;}' in JSX?

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi So in order to remove the React.Component part, am I allowed to add `this.localStream = null` right before navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia instead?

Comment: Added Demo in main answer post

Comment: I appreciate it! i will try to get that to work. Do you by any chance know how to start the video with a button as well with a "start button"?